# How do I make Google VM is visible from my Google VPN Gateway Tunnel

Tags: google-compute-engine

I have been struggling to make my Google VM accessible from Google VPN. I create a G-VPN tunnel and created a virtual machine. How do I verify it is accessible through this tunnel? Are there additional steps after this? I am not google in advanced networking things

Comment: Can you ping it?

Comment: Ping what please? I can ping G-VPN Gateway IP yes